# Does Google drive storage hack raid backups of my data just in case if their hard drives go down?

Tags: nas, storage, google-drive

I'm thinking about using the google cloud storage as my main storage device instead of buying a bunch of my own nas devices. But what i'm wondering is my data secure and backed up via with google's massive infrastructure. So my question is, how does google cloud storage handle redundancy in case of a drive failure? do they even use raid or is it something much better?

Comment: Are you asking what architecture google uses for google drive? Or are you asking about encryption? Or how google drive will handle data spread over RAID?

Comment: yea how do they handle storage over raid. im just curious to how do they store our data and also how is that data backed up. I have a bunch of family photos on there and wouldn't want them losing that data. Yea I know I can back them up, but I dont do it that often.

Comment: It's cloud, or **software as a service**, you can look through what that means to understand what the product is.

Comment: but how do they backup their data?

Comment: They have a data center..